# Unity - continue object inertia after drag has stopped?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

Ok, so I have an object that I control the rotation of using Mousedown in Unity, like this:

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

```
public class ObjectRotator : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float _sensitivity;
    private Vector3 _mouseReference;
    private Vector3 _mouseOffset;
    private Vector3 _rotation;
    private bool _isRotating;

    void Awake()
    {
        _sensitivity = 0.4f;
        _rotation = Vector3.zero;

    }


    //This include 
    void Update()
    {
        if (_isRotating)
        {

            // offset
            _mouseOffset = (Input.mousePosition - _mouseReference);

            // apply rotation
            _rotation.y = -(_mouseOffset.x + _mouseOffset.y) * _sensitivity;

            // rotate
            transform.Rotate(_rotation);

            // store mouse
            _mouseReference = Input.mousePosition;
        }

    }



    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        EndiTweens();
        // rotating flag
        _isRotating = true;

        // store mouse
        _mouseReference = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        // rotating flag
        _isRotating = false;
    }

}
```

This works well, except after OnMouseUp(), the object comes to a full stop. I want it to "glide" a little as if it has inertia. How can I implement this?

Tried this to lerp to a stopping value:

```
 //This include 
    void Update()
    {
        if(_isRotating && _isStopping)
        {
            // apply rotation
            t += Time.deltaTime * 1.1f;
            float rotDiff = Mathf.Lerp(2f, 0f, t); //some max
            _rotation.y = transform.rotation.y - rotDiff;


            print(_rotation.y);
            transform.Rotate(_rotation);

            if(t >= 1f)
            {
                _isRotating = false;
                _isStopping = false;
                t = 0f;
            }
        }
        else if (_isRotating)
        {

            // offset
            _mouseOffset = (Input.mousePosition - _mouseReference);

            // apply rotation
            _rotation.y = -(_mouseOffset.x + _mouseOffset.y) * _sensitivity;

            // rotate
            transform.Rotate(_rotation);

            // store mouse
            _mouseReference = Input.mousePosition;
        }

    }

    void EndiTweens()
    {
        iTween[] tweens = GetComponents<iTween>();
        foreach (iTween tween in tweens)
        {
            tween.time = 0;
            tween.SendMessage("Update");
        }

    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        EndiTweens();
        // rotating flag
        _isRotating = true;

        // store mouse
        _mouseReference = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        // rotating flag
        _isStopping = true;
       _isRotating = false;
    }
```

Comment: You need to work out the mouse velocity and apply it to the object. something like mousedelta/deltatime

Comment: Once you find that velocity you'll need to reduce it over time.  I think you'll find that you shouldn't set `_isRotating = false` in your `OnMouseUp` method.  You'll want to continue updating after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnMouseUp` you are setting `_isRotating = false`. Don't set this flag to false. Add another flag `_isStopping` and calculate rotation velocity decreasing on each frame. Set lowest velocity speed something like 0.001 after which set velocity to 0 or set `_isRotating = false`

Comment: Ok, see my question for what I've tried. I don't have velocity because I directly apply the rotation and didn't have a rigid body. So I tried lerping a rotation diff value from a max down to zero, where the object would eventually stop. But now none of it is working

Comment: @UserDude first issue in `OnMouseUp` you forget to remove `_isRotating = false;` Remove it. And this could be the only one issue :)